# Find ArrayList members and (Get-Process).id vs (1,2,3).ToString()

Tags: arrays, powershell, oop, arraylist, powershell-7.0

Let us look at the code below:

```
$r = New-Object System.Random
$r.GetType()
$r | Get-Member
```

I think I understand how it works. However, when I replace Random object with ArrayList:

```
$a = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$a.GetType()
$a | Get-Member
```

[Question 1] Get-Member call produces an error: "You must specify an object for the Get-Member cmdlet". What? $a is not an object? "$a.gettype()" says it is.

[Question 2] I understand ArrayList can hold other objects, but how do I get members for ArrayList itself, such as add(), clear(), etc which I found from the documentation? ISE also knows the members.

Let us look at the following 2 similar constructs:

```
$p = Get-Process
$p.GetType()
$p | Get-Member
$p.id[2]

$L = @(3,1,4,1,5,9,2,6,5,3)
$L.GetType()
$L | Get-Member
$L.ToString()[2]
```

[Question 3] $p is an array [of process objects], however, Get-Member does not show members of the array itself, but the members of the objects the array hold, does this make sense?

[Question 4] The array $p does not have a member "id", but $p.id operates on each element of the array, generating a list of @($p[0].id, $p[1].id, ...). Let us accept this is how it works in Powweshell, then the same should apply to to array $L, however, $L.ToString() results the literal string "System.Object[]", those exact 15 chars! And $L.ToString()[2] is "s"! Why there is no consistency?

[Edit] Question 4 used a bad example because ToString() is a method for the array as well as the number element. ToString() method on an array is to return the object type "System.Object[]". A better example is:

```
@([byte]67, [byte]97, [byte]116).tochar($null)
C
a
t
```

which shows that operation on a list, when not a list operation, operates on the element (unrolls) and then re-rolls back to a list. It seems to be Powershell is pragmatic, but at least consistent.

Comment: [q1] sending stuff across the pipeline _unrolls the collection_. since you put _nothing in the collection_ ... you send _nothing to the next command_. [*grin*]

Comment: [q2] to get the info on a collection, use `Get-Member -InputObject $Collection`. that works on the collection, not on the thing passed across the pipeline.

Comment: [q3] see the answer to [q1].

Comment: [q4] when you address a property of an item in the collection as if it was a collection property, you get all the properties with that name for the entire collection.

Comment: Thanks for the answers in the comment. What you said in [q4] applies not only to properties but also to method as well, as shown in the last example in the question (edited).

Comment: you are quite welcome! glad to have helped a little ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mr Lee_Dailey said, `$listofsomethings | get-member` will apply to the actual objects in the variable. If they are all the same, powershell can figure this out and will only output the information once. However, look at this example.

```
$array = [int]2,[string]"doug",[float]19.83

$array | Get-Member
```

You'll see it gives you the details for 3 distinct types, as there are three different types in this array. On the other hand, if you do

```
Get-Member -InputObject $array
```

You will see information about the array container itself. Additionally, the following command also looks at the container as well.

```
   $array.GetType().BaseType
```

To see the type of each member in the container's collection (not using the powershell auto unrolling of `$array | gm`) you'd have to loop over them.

```
$array.ForEach{$_.gettype()}
$array.ForEach{$_.gettype().basetype}
```

Now knowing this, it should be clear why `$p.id` works.. Powershell is "helping" you by effectively running this under the hood

```
$p | foreach id
```

Or written the same way as the $array foreach

```
$p.foreach{$_.id}
```

$arraylists are like arrays in that they can contain different type of objects.

```
$arraylist = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$arraylist.Add([int]2)
$arraylist.Add([string]"Stack Overflow")
$arraylist.Add([double]32.80)
```

You'll notice that each time you add an item to the arraylist, powershell outputs the index of where that item was added. It's commonplace to remove this `$null = $arraylist.add(...)`. This annoyance alone should be enough to discourage it's use, but the fact that it's deprecated in favor of the `System.Collections.Generic.List` lists should already lead you away from it. You specify the type of item the list is for such as [string],[int],[object],etc. It also doesn't have the side effect of spitting out index numbers when adding items.

You can create a list like this

```
$list = new-object System.Collections.Generic.List[string]
```

or

```
$list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()
```

And you can add/remove the same way you do with an arraylist.

Comment: Doug, thank you for the detailed reply, I got all the points, appreciate your help. I have two some minor questions not directly related to the main issue: [a] `Generic.List` only accepts elements of the same type so it is not a direct replacement for `ArrayList`? By the way, the annoyance you mentioned does not appear inside methods of a class (which basically a function). [b] `$p.id.gettype()` and `$p.foreach{$_.id}.gettype()` shows minor differences: `Object[]` vs `Collection`, do you know why? Collection is a name for a collect of object types, is there an object type called "Correction"?

Comment: You can define a list of objects `$list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()` and then add different types `$list.Add("a")` `$list.Add(123)`

Comment: `$p.foreach{$_.id}.gettype()` this is not getting the types of the items as you have it outside the `{ }` - put it inside `$p.foreach{$_.id.gettype()}`

Comment: Classes do not output anything unless you explicitly return or write-host. It is quite different than a function.

Comment: I do want to use `get type()` outside in `$p.foreach{$_.id}.gettype()` to build my own array of ID's without Powershell's implicit "unrolling" and "re-rolling" to understand the concept. Actually, the issue can be produced more easily: `((1,2,3).foreach{$_}).gettype()` is a _collection_, while `@((1,2,3).foreach{$_}).gettype()` shows an _array_. I guess in the former case, Powershell only see a bunch of output, while in the latter case Powershell knows I want a list. By the way, Powershell shows ``Collection`1 ``,  I also saw it in object declaration, what does `1 mean here?

Comment: @puravidaso - i THINK that `backtick 1` thing means that it has one axis.i've only seen a higher number on 2-dimension collections.